# `'errorformat'` incorrectly matching file name

Tags: errorformat

Consider the following `'errorformat'` configuration:

```
set errorformat=%f:%l:\ %m
```

And the following message:

```
%Warning-ASSIGNDLY: test.v:1: Unsupported: Ignoring delay.
```

While I expected that this message would not match, for some reason, after running `:make` Vim is identifying this as a valid error message with the file name `%Warning-ASSIGNDLY: test.v`. My `'isfname'` is with its default value (`@,48-57,/,.,-,_,+,,,#,$,%,~`), so I really don't understand how Vim is able to match a white space in the file name.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Tumbler41 [notes](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/8079/7600), `isfname` has to be turned on:

> If "%f" is followed by a '%' or a backslash, it will look for a sequence of 'isfname' characters.

I had no luck inserting a % (`%:` is an invalid format), but I succeeded with a backslash.  This requires a second backslash to escape the first.

```
:set efm=%f\\:%l:\ %
```

Then `set efm` shows the single backslash:

```
errorformat=%f\:%l: %m
```

Comment: The `%` following `%f` needs to be a part of the actual error format, so e.g. you can do `set efm=%f%*[:]%l:%m`.

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer: I have never used errorformat before.*

Edit: Deleted pointless stuff that was a mis-understanding of the question.

One other note. Earlier in the help doc it states:

> If "%f" is followed by a '%' or a
>   backslash, it will look for a sequence of 'isfname' characters.

Since yours doesn't, maybe that's why it can match a space?

As @JigglyNaga pointed out in the comments, make sure you use two back backslashes as without it `set` will try to escape the next character.

This is just my (non-expert) take on it. Hope it sparks something for you.

Comment: I had not tried appending the '%' or '\' before, but I just tried and it didn't help. I will also update my question explaining that I don't want to match this error message.

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry about the mis-understanding.

Comment: Don't worry about that, thanks a lot for trying to help me!

Comment: @Vitor did you try appending two backslashes - one to escape the other from `set`?

Comment: No I did not. And that does appear to work! :) Could you make it an answer, please?